# Azure Pipeline WebHook Resource Filter to Accept Multiple Values for a Path?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-webhooks-webhook-filters-filter?view=azure-pipelines) i can add filter to my webhook resource in my azure pipeline. but my need is to accept multiple values for a path/value. for example i want to accept 3 types of WorkItems like this:

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: UpdateWorkItemState
      connection: ReleaseNotePipeIineTrigger
      filters:
        - path: resource.revision.fields['System.State']
          value: 'Closed'
        - path: resource.revision.fields['System.WorkItemType']
          value:
            -'Feature'
            -'Bug'
            -'Issue'
```

But my pipeline doesn't trigger. seems only a single value is accepted. is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that we are not able to set multiple values for a path in Webhook resources.

Based on the doc: [resources.webhooks.webhook.filters.filter definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-webhooks-webhook-filters-filter?view=azure-pipelines)

```
filters:
- path: string # Required as first property. json path to select data from event payload.
  value: string # Required. Expected value for the filter to match.
```

The value field only supports  adding **String type** value in one line.  It doesn't support adding multiple value or other type of value(e.g. array).

I can fully understand your requirement. You can create a suggestion ticket in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report your requirement.